# SVG quality loss during scaling

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm using fabricjs to add an [animated sprite](http://fabricjs.com/animated-sprite) to my canvas. Unlike in the [demo](http://fabricjs.com/animated-sprite) on the fabricjs website I am using an .svg sprite not .png, so it should scale without quality loss.

However when I try and scale up the svg sprite the quality loss is huge. I have tested the sprite as a static object and it scales without any issues with the quality.

Video: https://streamable.com/ya5a

Here's an example, the top image is the sprite with it's default size and below that I have increased it's size and you can see the edges are nasty.

[image]

What could be causing the svg to have quality issues when scaling as an animated sprite?

Here is the sprite (crude test image) http://imgh.us/sprite1_2.svg

HTML/JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
  <script src="http://fabricjs.com/js/sprite.class.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #444;"></canvas>

  <div id="add">Click here to add Animated SVG sprite</div>

 <script> 
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var src1 = "img/sprite1_2.svg";

    $("#add").click(function(){
      fabric.Sprite.fromURL(src1, createSprite(1),{"width":50,"height":72});
    });

      function createSprite(i) {
      return function(sprite) {
        sprite.set({
        left: i * 100 + 50,
        top: i * 100 + 50,
        hasBorders: false,
        padding: 0,
        });
        canvas.add(sprite);
        setTimeout(function() {
        sprite.play();
        }, fabric.util.getRandomInt(1, 10) * 100);
      };
      }

      (function render() {
      canvas.renderAll();
      fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
    })();
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

(I've found the only way I can get this demo to work is in FF and if the svg is hosted locally, due to SecurityError. Which stopped me making a working fiddle/jsbin)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of fabricjs? I'm getting `fromURL is not defined` error with jQuery 2.2.4 and fabric 1.6.2.

Comment: @Zack Yeh I'm using fabricjs 1.6.2 which is the latest version I believe.

Comment: "Sprite" is not mentioned once in the docs http://fabricjs.com/docs/ are you sure that exists?

Comment: @Zack Yeh, there's a demo on their website: http://fabricjs.com/animated-sprite The animated sprite work (as you can see in my video), they just are not scaling without quality loss, which doesn't make sense to me as they're svgs :\

Comment: Your original may be a SVG, but I suspect that fabric only uses that as input to generate the output image, and that output image is not SVG. I'm not sure how to confirm this. Maybe it is worth a look through the actual fabric source to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Zack that's a really good point and would make sense based on what's occurring. I'll see what I can find from that. I think the answers may be in sprite.class.js then, as that's what handles the sprite.

Comment: A quick look at the script `http://fabricjs.com/js/sprite.class.js` shows the sprite to be the rendered result of the image url. So the sprite is always a bitmaped image. It should be relatively easy to change that script to allow you to use the SVG object, but svg will have a big performance hit as it is very slow to render compared to a bitmap image.

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks :) it is possible to fix that's a relief, I thought everything I was trying to achieve was going to be scuppered by this.

Comment: Why use the SVG, why not just render the SVG to a canvas at the max expected scale. The SVG will be rasterized by the browser every time you change its scale thus the memory requirement will be the same, and you will get the a much better performance. (as long as the max scale is not bigger than the canvas size)

Comment: Fabricjs has 3 methods : fabric.parseSVGDocument, fabric.loadSVGFromURL, and fabric.loadSVGFromString which will convert your svg to editable canvas drawings objects, without much performance issues, nor quality loss. Use it :-)

Comment: @Kaiido I think this refers to standard static svg only, not animated sprite but I may be wrong. As Blindman67 said the image is being stored as temporary image output in bitmap form regardless of it starting out as svg or any other format.

Comment: I think this is the reference to the bitmap in the sprite.class.js file, I have tired but I am unsure how to change it to svg: 

createSpriteImage: function(i) {
    var tmpCtx = this.tmpCanvasEl.getContext('2d');
    tmpCtx.clearRect(0, 0, this.tmpCanvasEl.width, this.tmpCanvasEl.height);
    tmpCtx.drawImage(this._element, -i * this.spriteWidth, 0);

    var dataURL = this.tmpCanvasEl.toDataURL('image/png');
    var tmpImg = fabric.util.createImage();

    tmpImg.src = dataURL;

    this.spriteImages.push(tmpImg);
  },